# Parsing custom date with NSDateFormatter

Tags: ios, swift, parsing, nsdateformatter

I receive from a remote database the following date:

```
Jan 30 2016 10:32:48:740PM
```

I want to store it in a NSDate object for other date-related usage.

I used the following code to parse it and convert it to NSdate:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "Asia/Riyadh")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "M dd yyyy HH:mm:ssz"

let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString("Jan 30 2016 10:32:48:740PM")

print(date)
```

However, `data` is always `nil`!

How can I parse properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all check [this](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime) document for date format.

Now, you have month and time format wrong. Change date format as,

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss:SSSa"
```

that should do it.